# The requested URL /chat//layercake/form_validation was not found on this server

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Codeigniter I am trying to call a function from `form action` and I get the following error:

> requested URL /chat//layercake/form_validation was not found on this server.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="contact" data-toggle="validator" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'/layercake/form_validation'; ?>">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="" required>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="4" name="message" required></textarea>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div   class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 alert">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your action url `base_url().'/layercake/form_validation';`  to  `base_url().'layercake/form_validation';`

Please look at your error. There are two `//` after `chat`.

Answer (score 0):

Your action `URL` is wrong. Change `action="<?php echo base_url().'/layercake/form_validation'; ?>"` this as following in `form` tag

```
action="<?php echo site_url('layercake/form_validation'); ?>"
```